# Can't figure out why angular binding won't work in codepen script

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use angular in codepen, which it seems to support, but I can't bind to my controller's `$scope` object for some reason.  I've tried a couple different versions of angular via `cdn` and there are other pens I've seen that are able to successfully use angular.  Can anyone tell me why my implementation isn't working?  [Here is the pen](http://codepen.io/AllenRMore/pen/NNqYKZ). the version of angular used is `1.4.0`.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="App">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="catControl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        {{2 + 2}} </br>
        {{'cat'}} </br>
        {{$scope.cat}} <!-- Why doesnt this one work? -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the JS code:

```
var App = angular.module("App", [])
  .controller("catControl", function($scope) {
    $scope.cat = 'cat';
  });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look again it is working the values are binded 4,Cat :-) what is the problem you see ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Why doesn't the third binding statement that accesses $scope.cat work?  I included the preceding expressions to show that angular was working, but not the controller.

Comment: Strange, I see two values: 4 followed by 'cat' but I expect a third value of 'cat' that I am not seeing.  Are you seeing 3 values while I am not?

Comment: You can't write $scope.cat. When you bind a controller to a div, the scope of that controller will preside over the entire div anyway.Check this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZNMRv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need learn more about `$scope`. We never user `{{$scope.key}}` in view. Instead we we use just `{{key}}` in View

Your code should be

```
<div class="container" ng-app="App">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="catControl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        {{2 + 2}} </br>
        {{'cat'}} </br>
        {{$scope.cat}} <!-- This will not work -->
        {{cat}} <!-- This will work -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

learn more about scope at [This link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)
& [This Link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed this.